# C# 7.5/9.0 Operators priority - try to find a complete summary

Tags: c#, operators

We are using the last version of c#. We need the complete table of Operators priority, but we can't find it.

For example, what's the priority here?

```
string c = a ?? string.Empty + "example";
```

where `a` is a string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence

Comment: @BillTür: Yep, that's it! But how is OP supposed to accept your answer, if you write it in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Credit for the link goes to Bill Tür, who answered in a comment.)*

> For example, what's the priority here?

The search term you are looking for is **operator precedence**.

The operator precedence is documented in the C# language reference, currently found at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence

Regarding your concrete example, `+` appears earlier in the list than `??` and, thus, has a higher precedence. This means that

```
a ?? b + c
```

is evaluated as

```
a ?? (b + c)
```

---

Note to address a common misconception: Operator precedence does **not** affect the **order of evaluation**: `a` is still evaluated before both `b` and `c`. Operands in C# are always evaluated [left-to-right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operand-evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

So, in your case, `a` will be checked if it's null or not. in case `a` is null, `c` will be assigned with the string "example". if `a` is not a null, `c` will be assigned with the `a` string value.

If you're used to ternary operators, you can translate:

```
string c = a ?? string.Empty + "example";
```

to:

```
string c = a != null ? a : string.Empty + "example";
```

Comment: This is a nice introduction to the null-coalescing operator, but how is that related to the question asked?